# An equivalent definition of the modulo relation

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $k$ be a fixed positive integer. Define binary relation $R$ as follows:

$$ (n,m) \in R \iff k\mid (n-m) $$

Then show that $(n,m) \in R \iff n$ and $m$ have the same remainder when you divide each by $k$ according to division algorithm.

Help is appreciated.

Comment: You should put the entire Question in the body text, not relying essentially on the title to ask for what you want.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any question there.

Comment: The definition in the post is the usual one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(1)$ ${}\qquad{}$ $m$, $n$ both leave the same remainder on division by $k$.

$(2)$ ${}\qquad{}$ $m=q_1 k + r$, ${}\quad{}$ $n=q_2 k + r$

$(3)$ ${}\qquad{}$ $n-m= (q_1-q_2)k$

$(4)$ ${}\qquad{}$ $n-m=(\text{something}\cdot k)$

$(5)$ ${}\qquad{}$ $k\mid (n-m)$

It's not hard to go from $(1)$ to $(2)$ to $(3)$ to $(4)$ to $(5)$.

Perhaps for now I'll leave it as an exercise to go back the other way.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $n=ak+b$ and $m=ck+d$ where $0\le b,d<k$.

$(n,m) \in R \iff k\mid(n-m) \iff k\mid((a-c)k+b-d) \iff k\mid(b-d) \iff b=d$

Answer (score 1):

Let $n = k*q+r$ and $m = k*s + t$, where $0 \leq r < k$ and $0 \leq t < k$. Every integer has that unique representation. Then $k \mid (n-m) \Longleftrightarrow k \mid (k*q+r-k*s-t) \Longleftrightarrow k \mid (r-t) \Longleftrightarrow r=t = 0$, because $|r-t| < k$, since $r,t \in [0,k)$.